# Сделать в линию две шкалы

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Не пойму в чем проблема, почему два индикатора в две строчки, а не в одну строку.

Может что-то не так написал.

Заранее спасибо за помощь. )

Код:

```css
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}
.healthbar{
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: auto;
    transition: width 500ms;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <section class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <h1 class="text-center">You</h1>
            <div class="healthbar">
                <div class="healthbar text-center" style="background-color:green; margin: 0;color: white;">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <h1 class="text-center">Monster</h1>
            <div class="healthbar">
                <div class="healthbar text-center" style="background-color:green; margin: 0;color: white;">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что `div` блочный элемент. Я так предполагаю что ваш стиль small-6 должен был изменять это в какой либо способ. Возможно эти стили не подключены или не написаны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам нужно добавить в css

```
section.row > * {
  float: left;
}
.small-6{
  width: 50%;
}
```